# Trying to load csv file to my postgres table using ETL pentaho data integration. Note: I am not a super user

Tags: database, postgresql, etl, pg-hba.conf

I installed the ETL pentaho data integration tool properly .

*When I try to connect my db.It is giving this error message.*

> Error connecting to database [test_db] : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
>   Error occurred while trying to connect to the database
>
> Error connecting to database: (using class org.postgresql.Driver)
>   FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "my host name", user "my user name", database "my database name", SSL off.

Note: I am not a super user.

how to edit the pg_hba.conf file.

Answer (score 0):

Your pg_hba.conf will be in your postgres installation folder, something like `/usr/local/var/postgres/pg_hba.conf`